# How to set multiple directories and extensions to export to a log file in batch

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to export a list of specific file extensions from different folder paths. My code is not working somehow.

```
@Echo on
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "SourceDir=C:\Users\Murray\Documents\Mainfile"
Set "Ext1=.ssl"
Set "Ext2=.conf"
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('Dir /B /A:-D "%SourceDir% ^| findstr /ie "%Ext1%" ^|
%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /ie "%Ext2%" ') do echo %%A  >> C:\Users\Murray\Documents\log.txt
Pause
```

What I want to overcome is to list all files from different directories and selected file extensions with full path. I would like to do this by setting variables. It is very likely that I am missing a few point. My main goal is to get full paths from a log text then copy them to the several directories depending on their extensions (Destination paths will be several and I will set them as variable similar to the listed code above not to use multiple `goto` submenus). Thanks in advance.

```
@Echo on
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "SourceDir=C:\Users\Murray\Documents\Mainfile"
Set "Ext1=.ssl"
Set "Ext2=.conf"
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('Dir /B /A:-D "%SourceDir%" ^| findstr /ie "%Ext1%" ') do echo %%A  >> C:\Users\Murray\Documents\log.txt
Pause
```

This code exports the list of all files with extension `.ssl` to the log.txt from `%SourceDir%` but I could not manage to add extensions which were defined with `%Ext2%` so that they can be listed in the same log.txt file. Actually, The real problem here I would like to learn is that how can I set multiple source variables (different folder paths and file extension) as in my example to my code? For instance, how can I use multiple variables with `Findstr`?

Comment: your posted code does not do anything close to what your are describing as the goal. consider editing your question and replacing the code with a step by step breakdown of what you seek to accomplish.

Comment: I have just edited my question as requested.

Comment: There is no point in using multiple `FINDSTR` commands as it is capable of accepting multiple search terms.  And there is no point in using `FINDSTR` at all as the `DIR` command will accept multiple file masks you want to search for.

Comment: My problem is to figure out how to use variables in order to shorten processes. Actually, I want to learn how to get things done without using multiple goto submenus. @Squashman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Dir` command accepts only one argument for source destination. if no argument is given, the current directory will be searched.

If you need to search subfolders as well, The `dir` command accepts the switch `/s` to search the source directory and all sub directories

To do what you seek, multiple sources can be defined in list form to a variable, then for loops can be used to iterate over each source as appropriate. `Pushd` can be used to switch the working directory to the current item in the sourcelist.

[For info on how to iterate over arrays in batch, see here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C38.9071)

```bat
@Echo off

Setlocal
:# define the directories to search
 set sourcelist="%Userprofile%\Desktop" "C:\Users\Murray\Documents\Mainfile"

:# define the extensions to search
 Set extlist=".ss1" ".conf"
 For %%G in (%extlist%)Do Set "[i]%%~G=0"

 For %%G in (%sourcelist%)Do (
  PUSHD %%G
  For %%H in (%extlist%)Do For /f "delims=" %%J in ('^
   dir /b /a:-d "*%%~H" 2^> nul ^| %__APPDIR__%findstr.exe /leic:"%%~H" ^
 ')Do (
   Set /a [i]%%~H+=1
   Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
   For %%v in (![i]%%~xH!)Do Endlocal & Set "%%~H[%%v]=%%~fJ"
  )
  POPD
 )

 Set .ss1

 Set .conf
 Pause
 Rem do stuff
Endlocal & Goto :Eof
```

the pipe through `findstr` ensures 'long' directories aren't falsely matched IE:".doc" ".docx"

this construct:

```bat
   Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
   For %%v in (![i]%%~xH!)Do Endlocal & Set "%%~xH[%%v]=%%~fJ"
```

allows the expansion of the current value of the count to be assigned to a faux array reference variable without consuming any `!` characters present in the filename.

- `%%~xH` exapands first to the current .ext value of the `%%H` for loop ie: .ss1, then delayed expansion occurs expanding ![i].ss1! to its value. the for metavariables are assigned to the resulting variable name after the delayed expansion environment is exited via `Endlocal` IE:

```
Endlocal & Set ".ss1[#]=C:\Users\Murray\Documents\Mainfile\filename.ss1"
```

- where `#` is the current count

This method of passing variables accross the endlocal is known as tunneling.

Comment: thank you very much. Though I need more time to figure out the logic behind the code.